# How to create postgres index for query using multiple fields

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to create postgres index for a query using multiple columns

JPA table declaration

```
@Index(name = "foo_a_b_idx", columnList = "a, b")
```

JPA repository implementation

```
List<Foo> findByAAndB(A a, B b);
```

If I have to sort by created_date descending as well should I change the index as follows

```
@Index(name = "foo_a_b_idx", columnList = "a, b, created_date desc")
```

Is the above index defintion correct even if we want to sort by creation_date descending. What JPA call should I use to support the above query?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up 2 things:

JPA call : findByAAndBOrderByCreatedDateDesc

Index: @Index(name = "foo_a_b_idx", columnList = "a, b, created_date")

The DBMS will use the index when ordering on created-date but you don't have to mention the order when defining the index.

Hope this helps.

Wim

Comment: Are you saying we can remove date from index definition, just define Index as @Index(name = "foo_a_b_idx", columnList = "a, b")

Comment: Everything is going to work (JPA call will work fine) but main advantage of indexes is performance. And the potential delay is entirely related to the volume. With smaller tables, and especially because you use filter already on 2 properties, the impact is going to be small. But, IMHO, the index the three properties is the cleanest impl.